# Capistrano Deploy remote: Invalid username or password Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, github, capistrano

Trying to deploy a rails app using Capistrano, but authentication fails. The output while executing Capistrano, shows the correct IP for the server(deploy@46.101.45.52), but the logfile shows (deploy@159.65.33.89), my previous IP.  I have ssh keys set on github, both for the server and the local development machine.

Capistrano log

```
    DEBUG [deb63a13] Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-geofly-production-david.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote https://github.com/uberdave/geofly.me.git HEAD )
 DEBUG [deb63a13]   remote: Invalid username or password.
 DEBUG [deb63a13]   f
 DEBUG [deb63a13]   atal: 
 DEBUG [deb63a13]   A
 DEBUG [deb63a13]   uthentication failed for '
 DEBUG [deb63a13]   h
 DEBUG [deb63a13]   ttps://github.com/uberdave/geofly.me.git/
```

Capfile

```
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.5.0'

# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"
# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"
require  'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'

require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/passenger'


# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

deploy.rb

```
 # config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano

lock "~> 3.10.1"



 set :passenger_restart_with_touch, false

set :application, "geofly"

set :repo_url, "git@github.com:uberdave/geofly.git"

#"ssh://github.com:uberdave/geofly.me.git"

#https://github.com/uberdave/geofly.me.git



set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/geofly'



append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"

append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "public/system", "public/uploads"
```

production.rb

```
server '46.101.45.52', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}
```

Comment: Probably its log from earlier when your server ip was set to that...does the server's ssh key have access to github ...?

Comment: yes, git clone works so I am assuming the key has access. running cap production deploy today, results in:
Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.10. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
I did install the mysql adapter, and I tried adding gem 'mysql2' , '0.3.10' to gemfile, but it would not install.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` make sure yo have the mysql development libraries installed

Comment: you need to run `bundle update mysql2` to update the gem since you updated the version.

Comment: yes, I have the libraries installed and I ran bundle update mysql2, but that failed

Comment: just remove your Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` again because mysql is locked to an earlier version

Comment: Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.10. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
i have added all the dependencies. Rake assets:precompile works on CL but I get this from cap production deploy.

Comment: Add `gem 'mysql2', '0.3.20'` with the exact version number and run `bundle update mysql2`

Comment: did as iamcaleberic suggests: Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.10.

Comment: remove the version number from `mysql` then run it

Comment: i have tried that too-to no avail

Comment: I really I am struck as to what is going on...

Comment: look at this similar issue on github https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/709

Comment: i have tried that too-to no avail   LoadError: Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.10. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.)--coming from capp deploy. I re-install the adapter and then same error again when i execute cap production deploy.

Comment: I am trying to avoid capistrano and github entirely by copying direct to the server now. I have learned my lesson with rails. keep everything updated if you want to keep the app. So much stuff breaks. Rails is definitely not upward compatible without a ton of hassles.

Comment: you have to learn to handle your dependencies correctly and it will be aright

Comment: The issues I am facing are not dependencies. I first wrote this app in 2014 in Rails 3.2. What is puzzling, is that rake works to create the databases, run the migrations, and precompile the assets. But Capistrano fails with a mysql2 error. Obviously mysql2 is working for rails, but not Capistrano. Looks like I will be rebuilding this app from scratch, if I have to.

Comment: Dummy me. I did not realize that capistrano was actually running the app at the server. iamcalibric's original suggestion of putting mysql2 version number in the Gemfile worked on the server side and now I am where I want to be serving the app on the server.

Comment: glad it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano was deploying the app,but the app was failing server side.